# Несколько owl - слайдеров тормозят страницу

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

В коде 3 раз вызывается слайдер `owlCarousel` и это несколько раз тормозит загрузку страницы. Если вызывать только два раза, то все в порядке, но если больше то время загрузки страницы что-то около 12-13 секунд. Пробовал другой слайдер `jcarousel`, но это не помогло. 
Есть ли какие-то варианты решения?

Comment: может это поможет - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/lazyLoad.html

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)